# Adding Blocks to Inactive Dispatch Queue

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I have a situation where it would be helpful to be able to add blocks to an inactive queue which is then activated after another event happens. However, the entire thread from which I call `dispatch_sync` gets locked if the dispatch queue is suspended/inactive.

Is something like this possible? If not what other options do I have?

An example (not my actual use case):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    dispatch_queue_t my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("my_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL_INACTIVE);

    void (^b)(int) = ^void(int c) {
        printf("%i\n", c);
    };

    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        dispatch_sync(my_queue, ^{ b(i); });
    }

    dispatch_activate(my_queue);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Using `dispatch_async` fixed the problem.

Working solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    dispatch_queue_t my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("my_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL_INACTIVE);

    void (^b)(int) = ^void(int c) {
        printf("%i\n", c);
    };

    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        dispatch_async(my_queue, ^{ b(i); });
    }

    dispatch_activate(my_queue);
    return 0;
}
```